# Copy-assigning C++ lambdas of the same type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

C++ lambdas have a deleted copy-assignment operator. I don't know why. However that limitation can be easily worked around. But I don't feel good about it. What could be wrong with the following approach? [Live code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zmqJKDtsuxYgDI2l).

```
template <class T> void assign(T& dest, T&& val)  { 
  dest.~T();   
  new (&dest) T(std::forward<T>(val)); 
}

auto make_lambda(int i) {   
  return [v=std::make_shared<int>(i)] {std::cout << *v << "\n"; }; 
}

int main() {  
  auto one = make_lambda(1);   
  assign(one, make_lambda(2));   
  one();  // prints 2 
}
```

There are possibly two reasons I can think of:

1. Construction may throw and `dest` main remain uninitialized and destroyed again later in main. Double deletion.
2. Destructor may throw if some badly written library throws in a destructor.

Exception during construction can be worked-around too with strong exception safety guarantee. Consider `assignv2`:

```
template <class T>
void assignv2(T& dest, const T& src) 
{
  static std::allocator<T> alloc;
  static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type storage;
  std::memcpy(&storage, &dest, sizeof(T));
  try {
    new (&dest) T(src);
  }
  catch(...) {
    std::memcpy(&dest, &storage, sizeof(T));
    throw;
  }
  reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage)->~T();
}
```

Comment: This smells very much of UB. Also: Why do this? You can just *write a class* that has the desired copy semantic, and put an `operator()` in it

Comment: The motivation for this dance is automatic memoization of functions.

Comment: Why do you need to store lambdas to memoize functions? You need only to store the function results.

Comment: I'm trying a C++17 variation of memoizing recursive functions: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2012/01/general-purpose-automatic-memoization.html The recursive function is written with knowledge of memoization. So each call to recursive function checks if a result is already available.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be able to (copy / move) assign lambdas.

```
class lambda {
    std::shared_ptr<int> v;
public:
    explicit lambda(int i) : v(make_shared(i)) {}
    void operator()() { std::cout << *v << "\n"; }
}

auto make_lambda(int i) {   
    return lambda(i);
}
```

Or, for the memoization case, where you don't change `memoise`:

```
template <typename Func>
auto memoized_recursion(Func func, Cache c = Cache::NO_RECLAIM)
{
  static std::unordered_map<Func, decltype(memoise(func))> functor_map;

  if(Cache::RECLAIM == c)
    return functor_map.insert_or_assign(func, memoize(func)).first->second;
  else
    return functor_map.insert(func, memoize(func)).first->second;
}
```

Comment: Lambdas can be replaced with a class in many (all?) cases. But where's the fun in that?

Comment: @Sumant whats the fun of making it more complicated than necessary? If thats your aim you could try to write it in assembler :P

Comment: @tobi303 Agreed. I'm trying to understand the nuances here. Hence asking on so.

Comment: @Sumant afaik lambdas are just syntactic sugar for functors and since c++11 you are allowed to put a class definition inside a function, so I guess there is nothing you can do with a lambda that you cannot do with a functor

Comment: @Sumant I think I have correctly adapted `memoized_recursion`, with no copy assignment in sight!